# Cleaning up json includes and usage

Tags: javascript, json, import, ecmascript-6

I am importing data from json like this

```
import data from './data.json'
```

where data.json looks somewhat similar to this

```
{
  "data": [
    {"title": "Some title", "text": "Some text"},
    {"title": "Some title", "text": "Some text"},
    {"title": "Some title", "text": "Some text"}
  ]
}
```

so to use it in my file I'd usually do something like `data.data[0].title` which in my opinion is not the cleanest way, ideally I'd like to use it like `data[0].title` is there a way I can include or edit my json file to acheive this?

Comment: To achieve what you want assign the value of the data property to another variable and use it instead of the JSON object like such `var data = oyurJSONObject.data;` then data becomes the array of objects held in the data property and you use it as such `data[0].title`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `import {data} from './data.json`. That will only import that `data` key from the object, and place it into a variable called `data`.

Comment: _`data.data[0].title`_ then i guess OP should have to do this which he is trying to avoid. correct me...

Comment: I have problem using `import` keyword even in node v6, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mido `import` is not yet supported, even in node 6.0. You'll need Babel to use it.